# Permissions on a folder for a web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, permissions

I'm writing a web application in Visual Studio 2017 CE that will have to write pdf files on a server folder. I'm still in the developing process, and when it comes to creating the file with this line of code while debugging:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
```

it gives me this exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Accesso al percorso 'C:\Users\myUserName\source\repos\Magazzino\Magazzino.WebUI\ricevute' negato.'

I have permissions on that folder, I'm in the Administrators group and I've give `IIS_IUSRS` full permissions on that folder. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your filePath code. I had a similair issue and had a lot of issues with a file path.I had to write mine like: var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory)

Update: rather than just using create, you could have used FileMode.OpenOrCreate, which will create the file should it not exist ;-)

Comment: The folder path is correct, what wasn’t correct was that at the end of the path was supposed to be the filename. It was null because of a coding error, I fixed that and worked. You’ve unconsciously given me a hint :) edit your answer accordingly and I’ll accept it